# Change iframe without changing code of this

Tags: google-maps

I have added permanently on my site this code:

```
<iframe class="actAsDiv" width="401" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;q=Adobe%20Systems%20Inc%2C%20Park%20Avenue%2C%20San%20Jose%2C%20CA&amp;aq=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;z=12&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Is there any chance to change the `scrolling =" no "` to `scrolling =" yes "` without edit this code. I can add everything but beside this code. Is it possible to add next to some code that will change the importance?

Comment: As I remember `scrolling =" no "` has no effect on the google map iframe API... what exactly do you want to accomplished?

Comment: I want to edit iframe but I can't changing text in this iframe line. Is any chance for this ?

Comment: sounds like you are hacking some website lol, if you can not change this line, you can modify it using javascript, you can look at this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp); or you can make another site that has only the iframe and let this website's iframe load your website(by hacking the dns server may be lol), so you have some control...

Comment: It's not hacking, I design in Adobe Muse, this is easy to use software and don't allow to edit advance presets of widgets (for example google maps). I can't add normal Google Maps code because this site is for non pro users and they have problem with edit code.

Comment: haha, i was just kidding. does the javascript not work? But I think the only thing matter for using the Google Maps Embed API is the URL, if you can insert your url, then that's good enough.

Comment: OK works, thanks so much for help ;)